# F1-Score and Accuracy for Text-Similarity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, model, metrics, evaluation

I am trying to understand how to calculate F1-Score and accuracy between texts while fine-tuning a QA model.

Let's assume we have this:

`labels = [I am fine, He was born in 1995, The Eiffel tower, dogs]`

`preds = [I am fine, born in 1995, Eiffel, dog]`

In this case, it is clear that the predictions are pretty accurate, but how can I measure the F1-Score here? Dog and dogs are not an exact match, but they are very similar.

Comment: Aren't `labels` actually `inputs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One popular metric for text similarity is the Levenshtein distance or edit distance, which measures the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions, or substitutions) required to transform one string into another.

Try implementing below code. Adjust `threshold` as per your requirement.

```
import Levenshtein

def text_similarity_evaluation(labels, preds, threshold=0.8):
    tp, fp, fn = 0, 0, 0

    for label, pred in zip(labels, preds):
        similarity_score = 1 - Levenshtein.distance(label, pred) / max(len(label), len(pred))
        if similarity_score >= threshold:
            tp += 1
        else:
            fp += 1

    fn = len(labels) - tp

    precision = tp / (tp + fp)
    recall = tp / (tp + fn)
    f1_score = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

    return precision, recall, f1_score

# Example usage
labels = ["I am fine", "He was born in 1995", "The Eiffel tower", "dogs"]
preds = ["I am fine", "born in 1995", "Eiffel", "dog"]

precision, recall, f1_score = text_similarity_evaluation(labels, preds, threshold=0.8)
print("Precision:", precision)
print("Recall:", recall)
print("F1-Score:", f1_score)
```

Comment: OP has not tagged their question as `python` (or with any other language tag, for that matter)